# I want to run a command everytime I login?

Tags: release-loki

I am running redshift, but it crashes everytime i logout, or suspend.
I have to run a single command everytime i login. I have tried adding it to .bashrc but it only works when a terminal is opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and install `redshift-gtk`

In the UI you will find an option to run it automatically (it uses autostart). On my machine it works almost flawlessly.

After turning that Autostart slider on, it will create a file `~/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop`. You can edit the line that starts with `exec` to configure various options. For example, for me I have edited that line this way:
`Exec=redshift-gtk -t 6500:5600`

Now it will automatically change color temperature to 5600 during night time.